# Angularjs check box selected values not identified

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-scope, selected

Hi this question already asked but that not solving my issue.

I'm passing checkbox values to controller but i can't identify which one is selected.

This is my code

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="days in formData.businessDays">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="business_days.Selected" ng-change=""><span>  {{days.name}}</span>
</div>
```

**Js:**

```
$scope.addData = function(form)
{
    $scope.formData.days_id = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.formData.businessDays, function(businessDays){
       //console.log(businessDays);
        if (businessDays.Selected) {
            $scope.formData.days_id.push(businessDays.value);
        }
    })
}

//this days data values
$scope.formData.businessDays = [{
                    name: "Monday",
                    value: "M",
                  }, {
                    name: "Tuesday",
                    value: "T",
                  }, {
                    name: "Wednesday",
                    value: "W",
                  }, {
                    name: "Thursday",
                    value: "Th",
                  }, {
                    name: "Friday",
                    value: "F",
                  }, {
                    name: "Saturday",
                    value: "S",
                  }, {
                    name: "Sunday",
                    value: "Su",
                  }, ];
```

This is my console image 
[image]

> I can't identify which on is selected values ?

Comment: WHat about fixing `ng-change=")"` in your code. Better if you can provide a demo example on plunkr.com

Comment: @ShashankVivek I will updated please check now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 <div class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="days in formdata.businessDays">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="days.selected" ng-click="selected(days)"> 
    <span> {{days.name}}</span>
 </div>
```

and in controller

```
 $scope.selected = function(d){
    console.log(d);

}

$scope.formdata = {};
$scope.formdata.businessDays = [{
    name: "Monday",
    value: "M",
}, {
    name: "Tuesday",
    value: "T",
}, {
    name: "Wednesday",
    value: "W",
}, {
    name: "Thursday",
    value: "Th",
}, {
    name: "Friday",
    value: "F",
}, {
    name: "Saturday",
    value: "S",
}, {
    name: "Sunday",
    value: "Su",
},];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer actually am also fix this issue please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide a property `selected` to each of the `object` in `$scope.formData.businessDays` in order to identify whether it is selected, something like :-

```
$scope.selectedItems = [];
  $scope.formData = {};
  $scope.formData.businessDays = [{
    name: "Monday",
    value: "M",
    selected: false
  }, {
    name: "Tuesday",
    value: "T",
    selected: false
  }, {
    name: "Wednesday",
    value: "W",
    selected: false
  }, {
    name: "Thursday",
    value: "Th",
    selected: false
  }, {
    name: "Friday",
    value: "F",
    selected: false
  }, {
    name: "Saturday",
    value: "S",
    selected: false
  }, {
    name: "Sunday",
    value: "Su",
    selected: false
  }];
  $scope.changed = function(value) {
    if (value.selected) {
      $scope.selectedItems.push(value.name);
    } else {
      var theIndex = $scope.selectedItems.indexOf(value.name);
      if (theIndex != -1) {
        $scope.selectedItems.splice(theIndex, 1);
      }
    }
  }
```

and subscribe to the `change` event of the `checkboxes` to keep the property up to date

```
<div class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="days in formData.businessDays">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="days.selected" ng-change="changed(days)"><span> {{days.name}} </span>
</div>
<div>
  <p>selected values</p>
  <label ng-repeat="item in selectedItems">{{item}} </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer actually am also fix this issue please check my answe

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-sm-3" ng-repeat="days in formData.businessDays">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="days.Selected" ng-change=")"><span>  {{days.name}}</span>
</div>


$scope.addData = function(form)
{
    $scope.formData.days_id = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.formData.businessDays, function(businessDays){
       //console.log(businessDays);
        if (businessDays.Selected) {
            $scope.formData.days_id.push(businessDays.value);
        }
    })
}
```